Can't see CommandLine Property when running a Get-EventLog
I am running this command:
Get-Eventlog -LogName Security -ComputerName GLOWING-GALAXY -InstanceId 4688 -Newest 3 | Select-Object CommandLine

but this is what I get
"CommandLine
-----------

"

But nothing displays in the command line property.
I am running Powershell as admin. When I actually logged into the machine itself as the same admin user and ran the same command, the property value for CommandLine was just listed as "C"

Get-EventLog is deprecated. So if you’re querying different OS versions results might be off. Try using Get-WinEvent

Try without the Select-Object and see if you get any results or use "| Format-List" to help debug this issue.

Are you sure there's a CommandLine field before you apply Select-Object? I'm asking because blank is the expected result for a non-existent field.

There might not be a commandline property, but you have to look in the eventdata.

I tend to use | ConvertTo-Json  on objects i want to quickly visually inspect (while debugging etc). Somtimes | ConvertTo-Json -Depth X is useful on large nested objects. Sending any output from Get-Eventlog to ConvertTo-Json will serialize the EventLog object(/s) and list its available properties and their values.

get-winevent @{logname='system'} | % properties

Looks like in process creation auditing, the commandline event data is blank.

This is how to get it after enabling process creation auditing, but commandline is $null for me too in win 10 22h2.  Oh, there's an extra group policy, "Include command line in process creation events" in a different place, "Administrative Templates\System\Audit Process Creation".  See the same link.
get-winevent @{logname='security';id=4688} -maxevents 3 | 
  % { [xml]$xml = $_.toxml(); $xml.event.eventdata.data } | 
  ? name -match 'newprocessname|commandline'

Name           #text
----           -----
NewProcessName C:\Windows\System32\WerFault.exe
CommandLine    C:\WINDOWS\system32\WerFault.exe -u -p 13576 -s 1444
NewProcessName C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Platform Manager\Runtime\EMAManageabilityServer\EMAManageabilityServer.exe
CommandLine    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Platform Manager\Runtime\EMAManageabilityServer\EMAManageabilityServer.exe"
NewProcessName C:\Windows\System32\WerFault.exe
CommandLine    C:\WINDOWS\system32\WerFault.exe -u -p 10292 -s 1576

